# What is the "chirped response FIR filter"?

Tags: filters, speech-processing, pitch, lpc

In [Pitch synchronous split-band LPC (PS-SBLPC) vocoder](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1215748) the authors describe an algorithm to identify pitch cycle boundaries. In "Pitch cycle detection" section, this sentence describes something that authors termed a "chirped response LPC analysis filter":

[image: quote from paper]

An LPC analysis filter is just a FIR filter with LPC-derived coefficients. What is the "chirped response" in relation to FIR filters? I understand that authors try to reduce severity of anti-resonances that can nullify whole useful signal, but how do they do it?

Answer (score -1):

I guess it is somehow related to chirp signals ([Chirp wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirp)). This kind of signal is sometimes used to determine the frequency response of a system.